# Moving from Custom CSS to Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been working with HTML CSS for a while but very new to bootstrap. I have following code. Code works fine but contains a lot of custom CSS. My HTML code and CSS code is shown below

```css
.container {
  padding: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 632px;
  height: 269px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  display: ms-flexbox;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.title {
  width: 291px;
  height: 54px;
  font-size: 49px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.1;
  letter-spacing: -0.8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.description {
  width: 468px;
  height: 23px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.28;
  letter-spacing: -0.03px;
  color: #333333;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button {
  width: 303px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f9c940 !important;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
    <div class="title">
      <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="button">Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make above code as responsive as possible using bootstrap. How can I convert above custom CSS into Bootstrap code as much as possible? Please help.

Comment: Can you make use of this? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

Comment: I tried but didn't got required output. That's why asked here

Comment: Ok then post the tried code here. We can help.

Comment: Don't have as of now.

Answer (score 0):

After intefrating bootstrap did you changed classes from custom to bootstrap??

> like e.g. you have given button as class name add bootstrap class of button `btn btn-warning` to your button and you will see changes.

```css
.container {
  padding: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 632px;
  height: 269px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  display: ms-flexbox;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.title {
  width: 291px;
  height: 54px;
  font-size: 49px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.1;
  letter-spacing: -0.8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.description {
  width: 468px;
  height: 23px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.28;
  letter-spacing: -0.03px;
  color: #333333;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button {
  width: 303px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f9c940 !important;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card rectangle">
    <div class="title card-body">
      <p>Title</p>
    
    <div class="description">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="button btn btn-warning">Start</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes . By studying official doc's I got to know simple concepts like buttons but not able to to make above rectangle and adding it's styles like width , height ,padding etc for rectangle as well as for tile and description. It would a good help if you can let me know and explain how can I do it

Comment: I added the `card` class of bootstrap with your `rectangle` class and `card-body` with title and included all other content in `card-body` by doing this all your content gets inside your card. as this process continues you can change you custom css to bootstrap or you could use both at the same time too.

Comment: How this card can be made of required dimension? As per widrh height and padding mentioned in css. Earlier when I tried using card I was getting card all over my page

Comment: while you are using card probably you have missed something either closing tag or class name. Is my solution worked??? Ask if any help needed.

Comment: Let me check your solution on my local. Will get back to you in 2 hrs travelling as of now

Comment: What if I want to give length and width and padding too using card and not in rectangle css

Comment: Means just want to control width height padding using bootstrap